# Send php variable with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I´m using an image uploading jQuery script and a short php script. They´re both included inside of the mainsite.php file.

Everything is working fine expect the transfer of the php variable `$usr_id`.

How can I send the php variable `$usr_id` via AJAX to my server sided script correctly?

**php code**

```
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $usr_id = $user->get('id');
```

**This is my try:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#but_upload").click(function () {

        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#file')[0].files;
        var userid = <?php echo $usr_id ?>;
              
        if (files.length > 0) {
            fd.append('file', files[0]);
            fd.append('userid', userid);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'imageupload/upload.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != 0) {
                        $("#img").attr("src", response);
                    } else {
                        alert('file not uploaded');
                    }
                },
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please select a file.");
        }
    });
  });
})
```

*Edit:* this is the form field code

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <div >
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is that button inside a form and form is reloading page due to not preventing default submit process?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I edited my post with the form field code.

Comment: Surely the user id is part of the session here? i would generally say its not a great idea to keep the user id in a place where it can be modified. If you must, you could use a hidden field with the user id in already, assuming the value renders at all?

Comment: What is the filename extension? Also, you don't have a semicolon after the php echo variable.